# Stream video from ftp server to iphone?

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, ftp, stream

I tried to search much but I can't figure out any tut or anything to do that. I only see stream video from server to iphone through http protocol.

I want to ask if ftp can stream video from ftp server to iphone ? And if the answer is YES then how to do ?
Please suggest me anything to do that.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that is impossible to stream video from ftp server to iphone. The APIs does not support this.
Thank you for your interest in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through this  [Apple FTP Example.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope this will give you some clue how to work with FTP

Comment: I tried. But it doesn't relate to stream video :). It only process image and file upload, download and display it.

Comment: You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584056/cocoa-read-nsinputstream-from-ftp-connection Hope this have similar question as yours.

Comment: Thank you. I received data from ftp server. But I only play the first piece of data. I can't play the rest.